# How to create users in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I have extended my UserManager with a new method create_inactive_user. But how do I use UserCreationForm?

```
class UserManager(UserManager):
    def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_active = False
        salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+user.username).hexdigest()
        user.activation_key = activation_key
        user.save()
        return user
```

I can see in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py that UserCreationForm is a ModelForm which saves the object, so how can I be sure to sign up the users though create_inactive_user() in my FormView?

Is it something like this:

```
class SignupView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        User.objects.create_inative_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password'])
        return super(SignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) does exactly what you're trying to do, with all views and forms included.  Looks like their approach is to use a generic form, not a model one.  From the quickstart doc:

> 1. A user signs up for an account by supplying a username, email address and password.
> 2. From this information, a new User object is created, with its is_active field set to False.  Additionally, an activation key is
>      generated and stored, and an email is sent to the user containing a
>      link to click to activate the account.
> 3. Upon clicking the activation link, the new account is made active (the is_active field is set to True); after this, the user can log in.